# Calling on a column in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Working with databases, I am getting strange results when I call on the getContact() function.

The function is as follows:

```
public List<Contact> getContacts(){
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT contact FROM contactlist", new String[] {});
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                contactList.add(contact);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contactList;
    }
```

As one can observe I am only trying to get the contact name from the following function. But I end up getting something like this:

```
0 NAME1 null
0 NAME2 null
0 NAME3 null
```

I have the following columns in my database:

```
id
contact
phoneNumber
```

Can somebody help me with this so I can only get back the NAME.

I am creating the database as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE contactList ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, contact TEXT, phoneNumber TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

Contact class:

```
public class Contact {

    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phoneNumber;

    public Contact(){

    }

    public Contact(int id, String name, String _phoneNumber){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._phoneNumber = _phoneNumber;
    }

    public Contact(String name, String _phoneNumber){
        this._name = name;
        this._phoneNumber = _phoneNumber;
    }

    public Contact(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
        this._phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: @jbihan sorry that was an editing mistake ...

Comment: When you say you get back something like this, followed by 3 results, are those the right names?

Comment: @Nicholas yes they are. The problem seems to be in the Contact class which maintains all the getters and setters of each contacts. The class is maintaining 3 records. a) Id b) Name and c) PhoneNumber ... thats why I am getting the results like 0 NAME1 null. Is there anyway I could omit these two fields (id and name) ?

Comment: @Nicholas you could check out the edited question.

Comment: So it's not really a database issue then if you are getting the names you expect. Where are you printing these values from? A contact will always have a field of id, name, and phone number, you can choose to just print out the name though, and leave out the things you have left not initialised

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("contact"));
```

Comment: where do i make the query ?

Comment: instead of contact.setName(cursor.getString(0)); try contact.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("contact")); I assume "contact" is one of the column name.

Comment: gives me the following error:                                           `09-18 06:47:46.892: E/AndroidRuntime(7306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqllitetrial/com.example.sqllitetrial.InsideDB}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4`

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the table. The error is because the column "contact" is not found in the cursor.

Comment: At that point the cursor is null. have you opened the DB to use?

Comment: You are creating a table named as "contacts" but in your select statement it is "SELECT contact FROM contactlist". It should be "SELECT contact FROM contacts"

Answer (score 0):

You sure you're opening the right DB? I know that I have multiple DBs and you may want to think about using SQLiteOpenHelper to open the DB and parse through it. Your query looks in general, but I would make sure you are getting entries in the DB by having a "select *" instead of a specific column and referencing the index of the column by using cursor.getColumnIndex("contact").

Oh, and make sure to close the cursor at the end.

Comment: don't mind the question, I am a little new to all of this. So if I use the cursor.getColumnIndex() will that not only give me the index number ? Rather then the text value of contact that I am seeking ?

Comment: Putting cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contact") will get you the column and the string in the column

Comment: Oh and you're missing a semi-colon at the end of your SQL statement to create the table.